# Como fazer para trocar a classe de um elemento - Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

Eu tenho um ícone do [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) no qual estou tentando fazer com que o elemento ao ser clicado, troque o ícone de `fa fa-plus` para um `fa fa-minus` e ao clicar novamente, o ícone volte para o `fa fa-plus`. Como posso fazer isso?

Eis o código daquilo que eu tenho até agora:

```
$("#fa").click(function(){
    var linhaClicada = $(this);

    if (linhaClicada.removeClass("fa fa-plus")) {
        linhaClicada.addClass("fa fa-minus");
        //$("#excluir").hide();
    }
    else if(linhaClicada.removeClass("fa fa-minus")){
        linhaClicada.addClass("fa fa-plus");
    }
});
```

> Obs: Consegui fazer com que ele troque do `fa fa-plus` para o `fa fa-minus`, mas não estou a conseguir fazê-lo voltar para o `fa fa-plus` quando clico de volta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte maneira:

```js
$('.minhaClass').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus')
});
```

```css
.minhaClass{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">

<span class="minhaClass"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i> Clica-me!</span>
```

Comment: O bom desse modelo de código é de não estar aplicando a função do clique diretamente no elemento `i`. Deste modo o clique não precisa ser exatamente no ícone, e sim no "contexto", ou seja, em todo o texto (inclusive o ícone) que pode/deve executar a ação esperada. Isso melhora o uso do elemento.

Comment: mas aqui nao esta indo ele sempre mantem o mesmo da uma olhada no meu codigo:    '$('.badge pull-right').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus')
});'

Comment: ignore meu comentario precisei colocar um id pois com minha classe nao pegou agora funfou obg amigo